# Unblock-File not working as intended

Tags: powershell

I have a `profile.ps1` script that I need to run, which was created by Conda application.
I have unblocked the file by running :
`Unblock-File -Path .\profile.ps1`

The command is executed successfully(I am assuming this as there were no errors, warnings, or output), but when I launch PowerShell in a new window, I get the error that `Running scripts on this computer is restricted`.

On the [Microsoft Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.3#example-7-unblock-a-script-to-run-it-without-changing-the-execution-policy), the example has the Execution Policy set to `RemoteSigned` and the use case of Unblock-File is documented.
Does this policy only work in this case, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want assistance with issue surrounding the execution policy, you will have to provide us PowerShell profile as an [edit] to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Unblock-File` to ignore execution policy is session-based. New powershell windows will not "remember" that you unblocked a specific file. If you want it to persist, you'll need to:

- Change your execution policy to allow running unsigned scripts (applies to all scripts)

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

- Actually sign the script with a certificate, using `Set-AuthenticodeSignature` for example
- Or unblock the file every time you open powershell, maybe by adding `Unblock-File` to your PS profile

`Unblock-File` is more for removing the "downloaded from internet" zone identifier from files than for messing with execution policies